# Xamarin: Unable to cater for multiple devices editing an existing project which initially catered for only 1 device

Tags: android, xamarin

Good day all, I am currently editing an existing project which was initially only created for a specific Tablet, However, I would like to make it compatible on any device.

The snag is, both "supports-screens and compatible-screens":

```html
<!--<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                    android:smallScreens="true"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:xlargeScreens="true"
                    android:largestWidthLimitDp="840"/>-->

  <compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="280" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="560" />

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="280" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="280" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="280" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="360" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="560" />
  </compatible-screens>
```

..seems NOT to work. I am really stuck with this. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to [compatible-screens document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html), you can find the following statements:

> The Android system does not read the  manifest element (neither at install-time nor at runtime). This element is informational only and may be used by external services (such as Google Play) to better understand the application's compatibility with specific screen configurations and enable filtering for users. Any screen configuration that is not declared in this element is a screen with which the application is not compatible. Thus, external services (such as Google Play) should not provide the application to devices with such screens.

So, `compatible-screens` only offer information for external services. If you want to offer support for devices with different screen sizes. You need to Provide different layouts for different screen sizes. For detailed steps of supporting multiple screens, please refer to [How to Support Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support).

Comment: Thank you, I read that document and didn't pick that up, mind my tardiness as this is my first attempt with Android Dev. To follow on from the proposed solution, the original devs created a separate solution with the project to handle all pages. Within the solution, there is a folder called pages which contain the different .xaml files. That being said, they also deleted the layout folder from the resources folder in the android solution which is separate. How do I then incorporate all that's within the pages folder into multiple layouts to cater for multiple screen support?

Comment: If you have `.xaml` file in your projects, your project is probably a [Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) project. Then you don't need to do anything for multiple screen support, because most controls in `Xamarin.Forms` will shrink to a size just big enough for its need. Please refer to [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/82719/how-to-handle-different-screen-sizes)  for details.

Comment: Correct, it is a Xamarins Forms project, I have read that thread as well and tried the proposal, however, the display seems to be way off when it loads on the device. So, for example, the menu bar is completely weird, the first link which is called "settings" displays one letter per line. In addition, there is a form which should load and resize to the device, however, this form appears really large and displays only approximately one column (out of 4) with an option to only vertical scroll. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: It's a very specific problem, You can create a new question together with some detailed xaml codes and screenshots.

Comment: Thanks @Elvis. I have created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498224/xamarin-forms-project-application-for-android-displaying-differently-on-differen), please share your thoughts.