# Xamarin Forms Project application for Android displaying differently on different devices

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin

I am new to Android dev and am currently editing an existing Xamarin Forms Project as it is not displaying correctly on different devices. I was advised that it should automatically resize to fit any screen, however, the display is incorrect when resized. Below is just a sample of my LoginPage.xaml and how the menu displays. The main page which contains a form to fill out also displays incorrectly on 1 column rather than over 4. This form should ideally resize to the device and allow zoom functionality. Any help and advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[login page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm7QD.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="XCallibre.XForms.Pages.PageLogin" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XCallibre.XForms.UserControls;assembly=XCallibre.XForms" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XCallibre.XForms.ViewModels;assembly=XCallibre.XForms" Title="Login" xmlns:labControls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms" xmlns:Prog="clr-namespace:XCallibre.XForms;assembly=XCallibre.XForms">
 <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="40">
   </RowDefinition>
   <RowDefinition Height="5*">
   </RowDefinition>
   <RowDefinition Height="12*">
   </RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
   </ColumnDefinition>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="End" Padding="10,10,10,10">
   <Image x:Name="btnMenu" HorizontalOptions="End" Source="LoginMenu.png">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
     <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowMenu}" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
   </Image>
  </StackLayout>
  <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="menuSettings" IsVisible="{Binding ShowMenuList}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10,0,10,0">
   <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Padding="10,10,10,10">
    <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="3*">
      </RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="12*">
      </RowDefinition>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="13*">
      </ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="13*">
      </ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3*">
      </ColumnDefinition>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
      <Label Text="Options" TextColor="White" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
     </StackLayout>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
      <Image Source="Close.png" HorizontalOptions="End">
       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HideMenu}" />
       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
      </Image>
     </StackLayout>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="10,10,0,5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="110">
       <Label Text="Settings" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowSetting}" />
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
       </Label>
       <Label Text="&gt;" HorizontalOptions="End" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18">
       </Label>
      </StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Help" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16">
       <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowHelpCommand}" />
       </Label.GestureRecognizers>
      </Label>
      <Label Text="About" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16">
       <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowAboutCommand}" />
       </Label.GestureRecognizers>
      </Label>
     </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
   </StackLayout>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
  <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Settings" IsVisible="{Binding ShowSettingList}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10,0,10,0">
   <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10,10,10,10">
    <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="3*">
      </RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="12*">
      </RowDefinition>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="13*">
      </ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="13*">
      </ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3*">
      </ColumnDefinition>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
      <Label Text="Options" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16">
       <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HideSettingList}" />
       </Label.GestureRecognizers>
      </Label>
     </StackLayout>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
      <Label Text="Settings" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
     </StackLayout>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
      <Image Source="Close.png" HorizontalOptions="End">
       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HideMenu}" />
       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
      </Image>
     </StackLayout>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="10,10,0,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
       <Label Text="Server" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
       <Entry x:Name="ServerUrl" Text="{Binding ServiceURL}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsUrlEnable}" WidthRequest="180" TextColor="Black" />
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
       <Label Text="Server Connection" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
       <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsServerConnection}" />
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsVisible="false">
       <Label Text="Auto Send GPS" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
       <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsAutoSendGPS}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsAutoSendEnable}" />
      </StackLayout>
     </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
   </StackLayout>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
  <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="{Binding ShowAbout}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10,0,10,0">
   <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10,10,10,10">
    <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="3*">
      </RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="12*">
      </RowDefinition>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="13*">
      </ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="13*">
      </ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="3*">
      </ColumnDefinition>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
      <Label Text="Options" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16">
       <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ShowAboutCommand}" />
       </Label.GestureRecognizers>
      </Label>
     </StackLayout>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
      <Label Text="About" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
     </StackLayout>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
      <Image Source="Close.png" HorizontalOptions="End">
       <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HideMenu}" />
       </Image.GestureRecognizers>
      </Image>
     </StackLayout>
     <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="8,10,5,5" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
       <Label Text="Version" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
       <Label Text="1.0.0" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="16"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
       <Label Text="support@xcallibre.com" FontSize="12" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
       <Label Text="+27 (0)87 365 3300" FontSize="12" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />
       <Label Text="copyright @ 2015 Xcallibre Pty LTD" FontSize="12" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />
      </StackLayout> 
     </StackLayout>
                   
    </Grid>
   </StackLayout>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
  <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*">
    </RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="45">
    </RowDefinition>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*">
    </ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="160">
    </ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="150">
    </ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="160">
    </ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*">
    </ColumnDefinition>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0,0,0,25">
    <Entry Placeholder="username" Text="{Binding UserName}" TextColor="#FBF9FB">
    </Entry>
    <Entry Placeholder="password" IsPassword="{Binding IsShowPassword}" Text="{Binding Password}" TextColor="#878784">
    </Entry>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Prog:CustomCheckBox VerticalOptions="Center" Checked="{Binding IsShowPasswordCheckBoxChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" WidthRequest="50">
       </Prog:CustomCheckBox>
       <Label Text="Show Password" FontSize="16" TextColor="#878784"/>
       </StackLayout>
    <Entry Placeholder="serviceURL" Text="{Binding LoginUrl}" IsEnabled="false" TextColor="#878784">
    </Entry>
   </StackLayout>
   <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btnLogin" Text="LOGIN" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" BackgroundColor="#FDFDFD">
   </Button>
  </Grid>
 </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I don't get where the problem is. The root Grid only have one `ColumnDefinition`, So of course it displays only one column. Could you offer more details about what is wrong?  Screenshots of correct or wrong layouts also helps.

Comment: The code above is for the Login screen which has the menu issue which I have sorted out by converting AbsoluteLayout to RelativeLayouts. The issue with the columns was just a description of a problem on the Main screen. In the screenshot here, you can see that the form display is incorrect and not scrollable.

Comment: The screenshot does not seem to attach. However, it is basically a screen with an A4 image which shows only approximately 1 column of the A4 image rather than the whole image.